# On the alleged ambiguity of the Ablative Absolute "Mutatis mutandis"

Tags: classical-latin, medieval-latin, gerundive, late-latin, ablative-absolute

According to the wikipedia entry of [*Mutatis mutandis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutatis_mutandis), "*Mutatis mutandis* is a Medieval Latin phrase meaning 'with things changed that should be changed' or 'having changed what needs to be changed' or 'once the necessary changes have been made'."

In Classical Latin, the subject of the Ablative Absolute clause ***mutatis mutandis*** would be the nominalized verbal adjective/gerundive  *mutandis* 'the things to be changed' and its predicate would be the perfect passive participle *mutatis* '(having been) changed'. One could wonder if a second (though less natural) reading of this Ablative Absolute could also be possible, a reading where *mutatis* would be the subject ('the things that were changed') and *mutandis* would be the predicate ('having to be changed'). From what I discussed in a related [post](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/12724/can-gerundives-be-predicates-of-ablative-absolutes) this second reading is not expected to be possible in Classical Latin but perhaps it could be possible in Late Latin and/or in Medieval Latin. For related discussion see also this [post](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/5750/why-does-the-substantive-come-second-in-mutatis-mutandis). It seems that Joonas thinks that this Ablative Absolute construction is potentially ambiguous. According to him, the two readings are: (1) "having changed what had to be changed"  (i.e., the conventional reading) and (2) "by changing what had been changed" (in my view, a controversial reading, at least in Classical Latin). He says "Both readings are reasonable". I don't think both readings are possible in Classical Latin. Only the first one (the conventional one) is possible. But what about in Medieval Latin? I was wondering if at this stage the gerundive could function as the predicate of an Ablative Absolute construction.

NB: To avoid possible confusions, let me clarify that I'm saying that *mutatis mutandis* cannot be interpreted as an Ablative Absolute (AA) construction (in Classical Latin) iff *mutandis* is the predicate of the AA. The predicative reading of *mutandis* is indeed possible in a sort of (syntactically lower) dominant-like gerundive construction like *mutatis mutandis tribunatum gessit* ('he spent the tribunate in changing what had been changed'. In syntactic terms, the AA is a sentential adjunct, whereas the dominant-like gerundive construction is part of the Verbal Phrase (VP). In the AA reading of *mutatis mutandis* in an example like *mutatis mutandis tribunatum gessit* **only** *mutatis* can be the predicate of the AA (in Classical Latin): 'having (been) changed what needed to be changed, he spent the tribunate'. Note that an obvious prediction of my analysis above is that both constituents (AA and predicative gerundival constructions) could coincide, i.e., something like *urbe capta, patribus insectandis tribunatum gessit* is perfect. Perhaps some of you will insist in labeling ("analyzing") both *urbe capta* and *patribus insectandis* as two examples of Ablative Absolutes on the basis that both involve a clausal subject-predicate relation. Fine but remember that they are two different syntactic types of clausal constituents. After all, Grammar is not just a matter of putting labels/taxonomy but is a matter of understanding!

Comment: You’re choosing a completely different construction if you’re translating *mutatis* as a perfect active participle, so I would say any detailed analysis is pretty meaningless

Comment: It seems to me that the meaning of mutatis mutandis is so obvious and generally accepted that it's not very helpful to debate it.

Comment: @Batavulus Let me frame it differently. What I discuss here is whether the **two** readings of the AA _mutatis mutandis_ discussed by Joonas in the third paragraph of his answer in https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/5750/why-does-the-substantive-come-second-in-mutatis-mutandis are **both** possible in Classical Latin. It is not obvious whether _mutandis_ (or any gerundive) can be the predicate of an AA: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/12724/can-gerundives-be-predicates-of-ablative-absolutes . The conventional reading of _mutatis mutandis_ is not at issue here.

Comment: I don't think I agree with your interpretation of the English phrase 'with things changed that should be changed': I take it as a less clunky way of saying 'with things that should be changed, changed', i.e. 'with those things that should be changed having been changed'. In that case the implied syntax of the Latin is the same as in the other two translations.

Comment: @TKR Thanks! I'll revise it. I misanalyzed the sentence "with things changed that should be changed" as it were said in my native Romance language. Nice syntactic difference here between English and Catalan!

Comment: @MPW I'm not sure if I understand your comment. The issue here has to do with whether the Ablative Absolute _mutatis mutandis_ can in principle have two readings: 1) the conventional one where _mutatis_ is the predicate and 2) a controversial one where _mutandis_ is the predicate. Joonas contends that "both readings are reasonable" but I disagree (gerundives are not expected to be found as predicates of Ablative Absolutes, at least in Classical Latin: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/12724/can-gerundives-be-predicates-of-ablative-absolutes ).

Comment: With all due respect, let's put it this way: mutatis mutandis means what it means as long as Latin is a language (has been for well over 2000 years, and it doesn't look like it's going away any time soon). I think the question relates to some hypothetical (but very popular) look at Latin as a kind of mathematics. I readily confess that that does not interest me.

Comment: @Mitomino: In Q: https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/15229/1982 we discussed the gerundive, in the oblique cases, losing its deontic & passive qualities, effectively becoming a gerund; but, still dictating agreement in case, number & gender. Here, "mutatis mutandis"  = "with the things which ought-to-be-changed (having been) changed", is an example of a gerundive in an AA-construction which retains its passive & deontic qualities. Did Pinkster contrast this with "omittendis doloribus" & "patriam ipsam inflammandam"?

Answer (score 1):

"mutatis mutandis" when translated into my  Croatian language (which is egually synthetic language like Latin) corresponds as - promijenivši ono što treba promijeniti - and when transformed into analytic English - by changing what needs to be changed.
It is a mixtum compositum of the AA and the Passive Periphrastic Conjugation.

Comment: Welcome to this site, Ivan, and thanks for your information on how this construction can be nicely translated into Croatian. I've been able to infer the grammar of _ono što treba promijeniti_ (which is, by the way, not so different from Catalan, my native language: 'allò (_ono_) que (_što_) caldria (_treba_) canviar (_promijeniti_)) but could you please tell me if "promijenivši" means '(by) changing' or rather '(by) having changed'? What grammatical form is "promijenivši"?