# Can we substantivate gerundives?

Tags: gerundive

Many participles in Latin are "substantivated": that is, they effectively become nouns - using the neutral gender either by plural of singular like *secretum* or *apertum*. Do we have examples of gerundives - which are also types of participles - become like nouns?

Can the Ciceronian quote: "*cavebo quae sunt cavenda*" be shortened to *cavebo cavenda*? Or else, it is impossible grammatically?

As noted by Mitomino in later times it appears to be possible. I think I've found another non-classical example: *et bene puerilem ostendit animum, qui per mobilitatem et inconstantiam frequenter **optat timenda*** (Serv.A.4.157.5).

Comment: Gerundives can be substantivized: e.g. _mutandis_ in the Ablative Absolute (AA) expression _mutatis mutandis_ (cf. https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/15476/on-the-alleged-ambiguity-of-the-ablative-absolute-mutatis-mutandis ).  So I guess a relevant clarification here is what one should understand by "we" in your question (e.g. could Cicero accept _mutatis mutandis_ as an AA or, for that matter, would _cavebo cavenda_ be an acceptable shortening of _cavebo quae sunt cavenda_ for him?). Interesting question! +1!

Comment: Would you considered a periphrastic expression to be substantive? For example "pradendum est" (it is time for lunch)

Comment: @TylerDurden, well, I'm not sure if that technically counts, but even if it does is not quite what I'm seeking here.

Answer (score 6):

There are some classical examples for this, here are some:

> Cogita enim quam multis militibus non semper sobriis et imperator et tribunus et
> centurio **tacenda** mandaverint. (SenPhil.Ep.83.12.5)

Looking *tacenda* we find another exmaple:

> ut ventum ad cenam est, dicenda tacenda locutus tandem dormitum dimittitur (Hor.Ep.1.7.72);

[Out of content We can read in 3 different ways either *tacenda* or *dicaenda* is substantive; or, thirdly, as Loeb has both substantives: "he chatted about anything and everything"]

Easier to search the genitive:

> animus intuens vera, peritus **fugiendorum** ac **petendorum**, non ex opinione, sed ex natura pretia rebus inponens (SenPhil.Ep.66.6.5)

> Fortitudo contemptrix **timendorum** est; (SenPhil.Ep.88.29.2)

That said, several times authors seem to be reluctant to substativize like the long *quae sunt caveda*.

Comment: These examples are really interesting! By the way, did you find similar examples in Cicero? For example, Pinkster, in his _Oxford Latin Syntax_ (see p. 1258, vol. I, 2015), gives this example from this author: _Stultitiam autem et timiditatem et iniustitiam et intemperantiam cum dicimus esse fugienda_ (Cic. _Fin._ 3.39). Pinkster states that in this example "_fugienda_ is substantival: ‘things to be avoided’" (p. 1258) but I do not think this is a good example of substantivation of a gerundive. Your examples are indeed clearer.

Comment: @Mitomino, I didn't find from Cicero. there were two examples that I rejected: 1) *ut duo genera propter se expetendorum reperiantur*.(I think *expetendorum* is masculine look at context from above. 2) *sed et alia timenda sunt ab aliisque et ab hoc ipso quae dantur* (here I think *alia* is the subs.)... But I merely skimmed the results I could have missed many but I don't think I missed too much. I hoped to find example from Cicero but didn;t.

Comment: @Mitomino, I can't see why Pinkster says this *fugienda* is "substantival" (maybe I have in mind another definition of substantival), it really looks that *stultita, et... et intemperantia* are the subjects... i.e., those are the things to be avoided.

Comment: Many thanks for this interesting example from Cicero: _ut duo genera propter se expetendorum reperiantur_.  As for Pinkster's example, there's some debate in the literature as to how one must understand cases that involve, e.g., a coordination of feminine subjects having a neuter predicate. The easy/traditional explanation is to say the the latter is substantival. Cf. also _Ni virtus fidesque vostra satis spectata mihi forent, nequiquam opportuna res cecidisset_ (Sall. _Cat._ 20.2).  Cf. the somewhat unexpected pl. neuter form _spectata_ with the expected pl. fem. form _spectatae_.

Comment: @Mitomino: Why do you dislike, "fugienda", in this context: "things-to-be-avoided", reads as valid as the other examples e.g. "skilled in the avoiding and the seeking" = "peritus fugiendorum ac petendorum"--gerundives (in oblique cases functioning as gerunds i.e. as verbal-nouns i.e. substantives [nouns)]. I was uncomfortable with, "fortitudo contemptrix timendorum est" = "strength despises fear"; lit. "the despiser of the fearings by strength". Is "the fearings" a good example of a substantive?

Comment: @tony Yes, I think that _timendorum_ in Seneca's example is a very good example of a substantivation of a gerundive. In contrast, _fugienda_ in Pinkster's (2015: 1258) example does not necessarily involve substantivation since its neuter gender could be attributed to the following semantic agreement rule pointed out by Dirk Panhuis (2006: 102): "Inanimate subjects with various abstract feminine subjects may have a neuter plural predicate" (cf. also Sallust's example above).

Comment: @tony See the relevant rule in Panhuis (2006: 102): https://books.google.es/books?id=mM9A9S9KDFoC&pg=PA102&lpg=PA102&dq=%22virtus+fidesque+vostra%22+panhuis&source=bl&ots=YOIqi-6ybu&sig=ACfU3U3QcPheIplq6aRokNyF_O-SqxVRxQ&hl=ca&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjz_4aQtZSDAxUqdqQEHXkmBlIQ6AF6BAgREAM#v=onepage&q=%22virtus%20fidesque%20vostra%22%20panhuis&f=false